# Enable/Disable item checkmarks in dropdown menus (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown menu:

[image]

Is it possible to have a function, that given a number, it enables the item checkmark (red dot) of the option that has index equal to the number passed as argument to the function?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to enable Level 3 Autonomy's checkmark while Level 2 is still active? Or are you trying to change the active selection from Level 2 to Level 3?

Comment: I am trying to have multiple options enabled. I just want to know if it is possible to enable checkmarks of certain options while not affecting the checkmarks of other options. I am not trying to change the active selection.

Comment: I think you'll have to rely on transform.Find to find the scroll view at runtime. Then, you'll find children at specified indices, find their checkmarks with transform.Find and enable them.